# $a \leq b$, is $a^b \leq b^a$ correct?

Tags: calculus

I have just thought about an interview question, it was maybe asked previously, but I thought about it myself.

> Consider, $a \leq b$, is $a^b \leq b^a$ correct? Justify.

I thought about solving it in the following manner, but don't end with a conclusive result.

Let's consider:
$$\begin{align}
a^b &\leq b^a \\
e^{\ln(a^b)} &\leq e^{\ln(b^a)} \\
\ln(a^b) &\leq \ln(b^a) \\
b\ln(a) &\leq a\ln(b)
\end{align}
$$
I know that $\ln(a) \leq \ln(b)$, but cannot conclude from there.
Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a slightly more systematic way of looking at it. 
You want to check whether 
$$a \le b \implies \frac{\log a}{a} \le \frac{\log b}{b}$$
This would be true *if* the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ 
mapping $x \mapsto \frac{\log x}{x}$ were an increasing function.

Now, if you know a little calculus, we can look at the derivative to 
get a bit of a clue. It's hopefully easy for you to check that 
$$f'(x) = \frac{1-\log x}{x^{2}}.$$

Now the relationship between increasing/decreasing functions and their 
derivatives is the sign of the derivative. It is *also* hopefully easy 
to see that 
$$f'(x) \text{ is } \begin{cases} 
\text{positive } & \text{ if } x < e \\
\text{zero } & \text{ if } x = e \\
\text{negative } & \text{ if } x > e
\end{cases}$$

**So**, $f$ is increasing, stationary, and decreasing on the respective intervals. 
Oh no! If $f$ is decreasing, then our desired property will fail. So pick some 
$e < a < b$, and you should get a counterexample. Indeed, 
$$3 \le 4 \text{ but } 3^{4} > 4^{3}$$
as (un)desired.

Comment: This has the nice side effect of proving a fact that looks _almost_ like the original proposition: if $e \leq a \leq b$ then $b^a \leq a^b.$

Comment: Thank you for this crystal clear answer. Indeed, I missed to check the derivative of $f(x)=\frac{log(x)}{x}$, as it gives all information needed to have a complete answer to the problem.

Comment: @Zizou23 No problem! Glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

*Counter-example*:

$2\le 5$, yet $\;2^5>5^2$.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the mistyping.

Comment: Certainly the problem is not formulated perfectly, as it just popped up in my mind. More opened question would be how do you compare $a^b$ to $b^a$ for $a\leq b$. Then, if it is possible to find general solutions for different constraints if required, such as $a\leq b \leq 0$ or $0\leq a \leq b$, for instance.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly valid to the question I posted. Can you edit it in such a way it answers to the following question: $a\leq b$ how do you compare $a^b$ to $b^a$? Thinking this question would be more interesting to the community.

Comment: You're right. However, speaking of $a^b$ and $b^a$ implies $a$ and $b$ are positive if they're not necessarily integers. Also comparing these powers amounts to $\frac{\ln a} a\le\frac{\ln b}b$, i.e. you have to determine whether the function $\frac{\ln x}x$ is increasing or decreasing. You can do that looking at the derivative.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When looking for counterexamples, I recommend trying the simplest cases first.

Are the signs of $a, b$ restricted in any way?  If not, try $a = -1, b = 2$.